# Memory leak for javascript setInterval

Tags: javascript, performance, timeout

Is there any difference between these 2 statements

```
setInterval(animateImage, 1000);

or 

setInterval('animateImage()', 1000);
```

Will the second statement be interpreted by the browser js engine is any different way that could cause memory leak or performance issues. Same is the case with the `setTimeout()` call. The application makes use of 4 timer calls with 1-2 sec intervals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The biggest difference is that the second statement will cause `animateImage()` to be evaluated in global scope.

This can lead to problems if

- `animateImage` is not in global scope
- `animateImage` has to access variables that are not in global scope

E.g. the following will **not** work:

```
function foo() {
    var answer = 42;
    function bar() {
        alert(answer);
    }
    setTimeout('bar()', 1000);
}

foo();
```

Actually there is never a reason to use the second statement, so the question about memory leaks is not relevant anymore ;)

And obviously, passing a direct reference to a function will be 'faster' than `eval`uating a string.

Answer (score 3):

Use the first one. It makes debugging nicer since there's no eval'd code involved, it is faster and cleaner. Eval is evil and it's good to avoid it whenever possible.

In case you ever need to pass an argument, use the following code:

```
setInterval(function() {
    animateImage(...);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

The second statement will *probably* be slightly slower and use more memory, but it wouldn't be significant either way. You should Use the first one regardless, because it's generally best to avoid using `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. You want to use callbacks to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using it like so:

```
setInterval(function(param1, param2){animateImage(param1, param2)}, 1000);
```

to pass parameters instead of passing them at the end